# Getting this error while using android volley(POST Method) : java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.0.2:4000

Tags: android, node.js, post, android-volley

I am trying to send a POST request to a node js server using Volley in android. For some reason it is throwing java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.43.252:4000 exception. I have ensured that my URL is not localhost. I am putting the IPv4 address which i am getting from ipconfig. What could be the possible reasons for my exception and what is the solution ?

Following is the code I am using :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        //if no error in response
                        if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //getting the user from the response
                            JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                            //creating a new user object
                            User user = new User(
                                    userJson.getInt("id"),
                                    userJson.getString("username"),
                                    userJson.getString("email"),
                                    userJson.getString("gender")
                            );

                            //storing the user in shared preferences
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                            //starting the profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

```js
 //Following is part of my code from node server
//in routes
app.post('/login', AuthenticateLogin.validateUser)


//in AuthenticateLogin.js
exports.validateUser = function(req, res, next){
 console.log('Hello');
 res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `4000` is the correct port that the node server is binding to?

Comment: Maybe the node server is only binding to localhost, and not the LAN IP?

Comment: When I am hitting the URL from browser/ Advanced Rest Client, it is working properly. It is just failing to hit it from the app. The url works fine even from browser of emulator